# php match values with a user defined formula stored in a table and perform the requested mathematical operation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user defined formula stored in a database table as string **"({Arrival_Date}-{Departure_Date})"**. I then have below rows selected from a table.

**Departure_Date**               **Arrival_Date**  
2015-01-01                         2015-03-01 
2015-02-01                         2015-02-10

I want to use formula ({Arrival_Date}-{Departure_Date}) and get the difference in days i.e (2015-03-01 - 2015-01-01) = 2 etc for all rows. Any suggestions on how i can match value with my formula?

Thank you in-advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have stored the two dates in two variables, you can try this:

```
<?php
$str1 = '2015-01-01';
$str2 = '2015-03-01';
$datetime1 = new DateTime($str1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($str2 );
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

BTW I don't know which format the DateTime accepts (YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-DD-MM) or if it depends on the server's international options.. If it doesn't work properly you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` to manually specify the fields.

EDIT:

I don't know much about curly braces templates, but if you want to get the result as a difference, you can convert the `DateTime` object in its timestamp representation:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($str1);
$datetimeTS1 = $datetime1->getTimestamp();
// Or, alternatively, you can use
$datetimeTS1 = $datetime1->format("U");
```

The two options should be the same for dates after January 1, 1970.

The two variables `$datetimeTS1` and `$datetimeTS2` are now two integers. Their difference is the difference between the two dates expressed in seconds (since there are 86400 seconds in a day, you will now just have to divide the result by 86400). You can also write

```
$datetimeTS1 = $datetime1->getTimestamp() / 86400;
$datetimeTS2 = $datetime2->getTimestamp() / 86400;
```

because the two dates do not have "half days".

Comment: thank you. But i want to replace formula ({Arrival_Date}-{Departure_Date}) with the values retrieved from database. i.e. am trying to do a template in which {} is a placeholder for a value which will be set.  In short what am trying to achieve is loop through a table get values and replace {placeHolder} in the formula.

Comment: Added an edit... Hope that this is what you meant ;)